# How can I add a role to a guildMember?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to give a user a role, but then I get this error:

```
error: member is not defined.
```

I would like to give the new user the `Test` role.
This is my attempt:

```js
client.on('message' , (message) =>{
    if(!message.member.user.bot && message.guild){
       if(message.content == '!test'){
            var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Test");
            member.roles.add(role);
        }
    }
})

client.login(config.token)
```

Comment: You should either destructure `member` from `message` (`const { member } = message`) or replace `member` with `message.member`.

Comment: I am new to programming. What line are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```js
var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Test");
```

and also this:

```
member.roles.add(role);
```

because you are not defining `member`. I think you just forgot the `message.` at the beginning.

You should change it to this:

```js
var role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Test");
message.member.roles.add(role);
```

---

You may consider fetching roles by their `ID` in case the name gets changed.
You then want to use:

```
message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id)
```

Comment: But if I do it as you say it says: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Access

Comment: @PaulTubeTV Does your bot have all the necessary permissions to manage roles?

Comment: The Bot has Administrator Permissions.

Comment: Read [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#missing-permissions) from the official documentation and check if it fixes your problem. Maybe you just misspelled the name of the role

Comment: And maybe try getting the role by it's ID

Comment: Like here?: ``var role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "830147908337795092");
            message.member.roles.add(role);

Comment: again: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

Comment: Have you already checked that none of the [cases](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#missing-permissions) apply to your bot?

Comment: The docs say "Granting the ADMINISTRATOR permission does not skip any hierarchical check!". So it could be that the bot has `ADMINISTRATOR` rights, but still lacks the permission for e.g. `VIEW_CHANNEL` or `MANAGE_ROLES`. Check if it has these roles

Comment: I finally did it!!! The role I wanted to give was higher than that of the bot.

Comment: I have 1 more question: How can i give a new User a role?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/understanding/roles.md#add-a-member-to-a-role)

Comment: @PaulTubeTV Would be nice for me and other people with the same issue, if you could mark the answer accepted answer :)